# How to fully utilise `lwt` in this case

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-lwt

Here is what I am going to do:

I have a list of `task` and I need to run them all every 1 hour (*scheduling*).

All those tasks are similar. for example, for one task, I need to download some data from a server (using http protocol and would take 5 - 8 seconds) and then do a computation on the data (would take 1 - 5 seconds).

---

I think I can use `lwt` to achieve these, but can't figure out the best way for efficiency.

---

For the task **scheduling** part, I can do like this ([How to schedule a task in OCaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091116/how-to-schedule-a-task-in-ocaml)):

```
let rec start () = 
  (Lwt_unix.sleep 1.)  >>= (fun () -> print_endline "Hello, world !"; start ())

let _ = Lwt_main.run (start())
```

---

The questions come from the actual **do_task** part.

So a task involves `http download` and `computation`.

The `http download` part would have to wait for 5 to 8 seconds. If I really execute each task one by one, then it wastes the bandwidth and of course, I wish the download process of all tasks to be in parallel. So **should I put this download part to lwt? and will lwt handle all the downloads in parallel?**

By code, **should I do like this?**:

```
let content = function
  | Some (_, body) -> Cohttp_lwt_unix.Body.string_of_body body
  | _ -> return ""


let download task = 
  Cohttp_lwt_unix.Client.get ("http://dataserver/task?name="^task.name)

let get_data task = 
  (download task)  >>= (fun response -> Lwt.return (Content response))

let do_task task = 
  (get_data task) >>= (fun data -> Lwt.return_unit (calculate data))
```

---

So, through the code above, will all tasks be executed in parallel, at least for the `http download` part?

For calculation part, will all calculations be executed in sequence?

Furthermore, can any one briefly describe the mechanism of `lwt`? Internally, what is the logic of `light weight thread`? Why can it handle IO in parallel?

Comment: Let me address your question about `lwt` and light weight threads: [lecture on monads](http://www.ii.uni.wroc.pl/~lukstafi/pmwiki/uploads/Functional/functional-lecture08.pdf) (the [course](http://www.ii.uni.wroc.pl/~lukstafi/pmwiki/index.php?n=Functional.Functional)) and [Jerome Vouillon “Lwt: a Cooperative Thread Library”](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~vouillon/publi/lwt.pdf). (The same links as in my comment in the other thread.)

Comment: @lukstafi: you should add this as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @gasche -- [no link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) :-)

Comment: @lukstafi: sure, StackOverflow would rather have you manually typeset Jérôme's article inside StackOverflow, so that they get more google hits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do parallel computation using lwt, you can check the [lwt_list module](http://ocsigen.org/lwt/api/Lwt_list), and especially iter_p.

```
val iter_p : ('a -> unit Lwt.t) -> 'a list -> unit Lwt.t
```

iter_p f l call the function f on each element of l, then waits for all the threads to terminate. For your purpose, it would look like :

```
let do_tasks tasks = List.iter_p do_task tasks
```

Assuming that "tasks" is a list of task.

Comment: Do I need to enable `task` to be `lwt supported`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by lwt supported? A task can be any type you want (see that iter_p takes an a' list). The only necessity is that do_task returns Lwt (if it doesn't naturally, just put Lwt.return () at the end)